# IIS Allowing random strings after filename

Tags: iis-8.5

I host several websites on IIS and recently found that on one website I have users adding additional characters at the end of a valid URI and IIS returns the file. I would have expected an error. The requests appear to be a cache busting technique, just trying to understand how adding extra characters doesn't result in an error. An example is a request for myfile.t19.htm/58sbcaiqtsbj8p7n8tkl still successfully returns myfile.t19.htm. They do this on several different files and file types so I'm still working on filters to stop it, but still want to understand how it happens in the first place.

Comment: That part is called path info, and is always considered valid part of a URL, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo?view=netframework-4.8#remarks So get used to it please.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I don't consider it a great solution, but it's working so far. I added a URLRewrite rule like this:

````
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*.htm/*" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="*.stm/*" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="400" statusReason="Invalid Request" statusDescription="You have made an invalid request." />
                </rule>```
````